# Webview can't scroll

Tags: xamarin, webview

I've got this Xamarin Forms page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp1"
             x:Class="TestApp1.MainPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <WebView Source="http://www.google.de" HeightRequest="3000" WidthRequest="100"/>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

When I open my app, enter anything in the google prompt, I can't scroll on the results page. How do I enable this?

When I google for "xamarin webview enable scrolling" I only find information about disabling it...

Comment: Considered that the height request does so it thinks the WebView is so high that it doesn't need to scroll?

Comment: what platform you are testing on?

Comment: Found out that it had to do with the stacklayout. If I dont have the webview in a stacklayout it scrolls just fine. But then I ask myself, how do I align any other controls on a form to have the user be able to access options or something like that and still having the webview taking up the rest of the space.

Comment: Im testing on Windows Phone 10

Comment: On Android it works with stack layout well. I can try to test on Windows phone 8. Does it work on phone 8 for you? Can you provide an image what you are trying to achieve on this page? BTW. setting width and height requests on Android doesn't seem to have any effect. I think you should use HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions

Comment: I want to have f.e. a button on the top of the which brings the user to a options screen. Can you tell me how to tell the webview to take up the rest of the space?

Comment: So, the button and then webview under it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126555/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-ravior).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your own renderer and override this method as follows:

```
public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
}
```

[Please find details in this link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5205#issuecomment-507530412)

Comment: After updating to Android SDK 28 and updating Xamarin.Forms along with it my WebViews weren't scrolling anymore but this fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ButtonRendererDemo.WebViewPage">

  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10" Spacing="10">
      <Button Text="Press me" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Green"/>        
      <WebView Source="http://www.google.de" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>    
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was inside the `<WebView/>`, I had set a static HeightRequest and WidthRequest - because the documentation said those were required if you used a `<StackLayout>` - but this wasn't true

Deleting those and adding the **VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"** and **HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"** , solved the problem for me and allowed me to scroll as expected.

```
<WebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Source="https://google.com/"/>
```

Comment: Brilliant. This worked for me on targeting Android 33.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in android very well

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView),typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App.Droid.Renderers
{
    class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
 
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
 
        public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
        }
    }
}
```