# How Open PDF files on Xamarin WebView

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.android

I am trying to open a pdf file on a Xamarin project using webview and
i was able to do it using the following :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ViewReport);

        var mywebview = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);

        var myurl= "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";

        mywebview.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
        mywebview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        mywebview.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
        mywebview.LoadUrl(myurl);

        mywebview.SetWebViewClient(new PodWebViewClient());


}
```

My problem is that the PDF file that i am trying open is created via Itextsharp from my MVC project:

```
public ActionResult Print() 
{

        var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
        document.Open();
        string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Content/HTMTemplate/pdf_template.htm"), Encoding.Unicode);

        //====================
        // do something here...
        //====================

        FontFactory.Register(Server.MapPath("~/fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF"));

        StyleSheet ST = new StyleSheet();
        ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "Arial Unicode MS");
        ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

        var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(contents), ST);
        foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
            document.Add(htmlElement as IElement);
        document.Close();

        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = "samplepdf.pdf",
            Inline = true
        };

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());//open in browser
        return File(output.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
}
```

but when i did the following:

```
 var myurl= "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.sample.com/doc/print";
```

i was shown a text file with html tags and not my pdf file.

How should i fix this? I think my problem lies in my pdf file but I don't know which is it as I was able to open the pdf in my browser..  Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) and call it like this

```
Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(pdfWebView.Uri)));
```

[Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/) you find much more details about this approach (used for Xamarin.Forms).

Comment: Unfortunately, pdfjs has big problems.  The biggest problem for me was that pdfjs does not support touch gestures !!!!!  i.e. you cannot navigate and zoom the document using the touch gestures !
For me , it is not usable and not acceptable by any user.

Comment: I found the solution for the not-responding-to-gestures. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56943170/592651